# Adding a View when onValueChange - SegmentController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a segment control added to the navigation bar. It works fine. When i click on a segment (say index `0`) it should load `UIView` `A` for me. and when i click on segment `1` it should load `UIView` `B` for me.

I have initialized `UIVIew` `A` in my `.h` file. and i am accessing it in the `.m` file as follows;

Here i am adding a Button and a label to View A

```
UIButton *buttonAdded= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    signUpButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 50);
......

[self.viewA addSubview:buttonAdded]; 
// similarly added a label too
[self.viewA addSubview:labelAdded];
```

Now i added another Button and a Label to View B as the previous code;

```
// i have not shown how to declare a button and label, coz its same as above
[self.viewB addSubview:buttonAddedB]; 
[self.viewB addSubview:labelAddedB];
```

**EDIT: I ADDED BOTH THESE VIEWS (View A & View B) IN THE VIEWDIDLOAD METHOD.**

The problem is that when i click the segments nothing appears on the screen. Can someone please help me modify the code so it will work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your viewA and viewB are NULL.

You have not allocated/initialized your viewA.  There needs to be code somewhere that either hooks up a view from your nib (an IBOutlet), or you need something like this:

```
 UIView *viewA = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
```

Then you can use viewA.

Comment: I am not using `IB` only code. What is myFrame ? can i say `initWithRect:CGRectMake(x,y,width,heigth)` instead on `initWithFrame` ?

Comment: You can say `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)`